# DMV request for "Description" of the table for Power BI dataset

Tags: sql, powerbi, ssas, dmv

What I am trying to achieve is to add tables and columns descriptions programmatically to a Power BI dataset.

For this reason, I use Server Analysis Services to get access to the metadata.
I run a simple request:

```
select *
from $System.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS
```

As a result, I get a table with columns names:

1. ID
2. TableID
3. Name
4. Description
5. ....

Now I want to select where the "Description" is empty.

```
select *
from $System.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS 
where Description IS NULL
```

But I can't, I always get a syntax error:

```
Query (3, 7) The syntax for 'Description' is incorrect.
```

SQL reads it as a command and I don't know how to avoid it.
I have tried adding quotes and double quotes to the name of the columns, I tried adding a table reference and all of these combined, but nothing helps.

It works for "TableID" for example.

Answer (score 1):

This one works:

```
select *
from $System.TMSCHEMA_PARTITIONS 
where len([Description]) = 0
```